# Using params on template helpers from Iron Router in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using a router with this specific route:

```
Router.route('/organizations/:id', function () {
  this.render('organizationDetail', {id: this.params.id});
});
```

This renders 'organizationDetail' template.

I have this helpers for that template:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.organizationDetail.helpers({
    organization: function() {
        this.params.id????
        return FindById(id);
    }
  });
}
```

How can I access `id` variable to ask for the correct object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put that parameter into your data context:

```
Router.route('/organizations/:id', function () {
  this.render('organizationDetail', {
      data: function() {
         return {id: this.params.id};
      }
  });
});
```

Then you can use it straight from the `this` object, which holds the data context in helpers:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.organizationDetail.helpers({
    organization: function() {
        return FindById(this.id);
    }
  });
}
```